# Creating asynchronous WCF clients without using Service References

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

Currently I do not use Service References as I feel the code it autogenerates is more weight than I need. Instead I generate a proxy class by doing:

```
public class MyClient : ClientBase<IMyService>, IMyService
```

This has worked great for me, no proxy classes are generated so I reuse the same datatypes. But this only lets me create synchronous client methods.

What would it take to generate async versions? I have taken a look at the autogenerated code that adding a Service Reference would do and it seems like soo much boilerplate. A ton of begin/end/onbegin/oncomplete associated event arg datatypes etc etc.

Is there a simpler way with less scaffolding needed to create async client methods?
My ultimate end goal is to be able to use the new c# 5 async/await keywords on webservice clients

Comment: How do you measure this "weight"? Have you done some performance analysis?

Comment: when I say weight, I dont mean a performance penalty, but rather just the sheer volume of code generated. I would prefer something cleaner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always author a contract `IMyAsyncService` that is exactly like `IMyService` but uses the Begin/End async pattern (and has `[ServiceContract(Name="IMyService")]` to keep the same name).  It will be the same wire contract, and work with `ClientBase`, but now you have async methods you can use with `await`.

Comment: I thought about that as well, but I took a look at some examples for implementing the Async pattern on the server side, and you still have to create a bunch of custom AsyncResult types for every Begin/End pair...which to me seems not as clean.

Comment: Also the actual "work" of the method happens in your custom types and not in the Begin or End block, so it further separates the intent of the method from the implementation

Comment: You don't need to do this on the server, only on the client.  Leave the server and IMyService as-is.  Just add a new async client contract type.  It will be compatible with the server, but do the async pattern.

Comment: I might have to go this route..I was hoping not to have to maintain a separate client interface contract as there is the danger that it can get out of sync with the service interface contract, but I may have no choice. Doing it the way you suggest, I don't have to generate proxy datatypes which is the biggest win

Comment: I didn't realize making a WCF service call asynchronously was this simple. Tried it and worked beautifully. Very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think adding this 
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]

to your method declaration in the Interface on your services will determine its async.

Answer (score 0):

The CTP for async/await is just a preview of the support for these features. They plan to fully integrate them into WCF.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/11/13/simplified-asynchronous-programming-model-in-wcf-with-async-await.aspx